# Django is downloading file instead of displaying it

Tags: html, django

I am trying to display an HTML file from my Django code. but my file is getting downloaded instead of displaying.

Following is my code:

```
@api_view(['GET'])

def download_y9cfile1(request, file_name):  

    filePath = CommonUtils.get_absolute_file_path('app', 'static', 'generated', 'HTML' , file_name)
    return render(request, file_name)
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline'` ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Now I have used response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline'. Now my excel is not getting downloaded. But I am not able to see all the contents on the webpage.   
My excel is having 2 TABS, but the data which is coming on webpage does not have all the data from the Excel. Maybe the code is not catching the css things.

Answer (score 4):

#### `render()`

[render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) is supposed to work with a django template name, not the complete file input. So, you could try placing the generated file in the template path (do not add the static directory to the template paths, though!) and use the template's relative path as argument.

#### Regular HttpResponse

Or you load the HTML content as file stream and return it in a regular response with content type set to `text/html`.

#### Staticfiles

Of course, you could also use the the [staticfiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) module to simply serve that html file the same way it serves JS and CSS files. The path from which you load the file suggests that you actually simply want to serve a static resource. That would be the Django way.

More on staticfiles (reading the documentation also helps):

If this is in `<project_dir>/<app_dir>/settings/base.py`:

```
APP_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(project_module.__file__))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(APP_DIR)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # this would contain your "generated" directory
    # you can link several directories here if you'd rather
    # have "generated" as a root directory (url wise)
    os.path.join(APP_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static_collected')

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    # 'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)
```

In your top most `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
] + static.static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', never_cache(serve_static)),
        # url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ]
```

On production, `static_collected` would best be served by Nginx or Apache Http. If you need special URLs for your generated files, however, you might really need an explicit view for those, and a URL pattern definition.

#### CSS Resources / Template Solution

Example for your Django templates that would automatically create the correct URLs:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'lib/css/jquery-ui.min.css' %}"/>
```

You might want to reconsider changing your generated htmls to Django templates in order to avoid including hard coded static URLs inside. For example, you could generate only the vital part and then include it as context variable when rendering the response using a super template:

`views.py`

```
class GeneratedFileView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'templates/super_generated_view.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        gc = ...  # get the generated content here, as string
        return super().get_context_data(generated_content=gc, **kwargs)
```

Everything else is [TemplateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview) magic.

`templates/super_generated_view.html`

```
<!doctype html>

{% load static compress %}

<html lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    ..... css and js etc. directives
</head>
<body>
    {{ generated_content }}
</body>
```

This is just a quick example. If you need CSS/JS depending on the generated content, you might need a more refined logic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am very new to Django. Can you please tell me how can I load an HTML in django ? Content type I used as text/html but it is not displaying the entire data on the webpage. only few things are getting displayed. Maybe it is not picking up the relevant CSS files.

Comment: I've added an example on how to handle CSS files. Try to find examples in github projects that show how to include CSS files the Django way. It definitely is not easy to grok the magic right away.